# Get query return unicode symbols

Tags: php, curl, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I use cURL, and after get query I recive next html code:

```
$rezult = '<h5>\u0420\u0443\u0431\u0440\u0438\u043a\u0430:&lt;\/h5&gt;\n\t<select id="\&quot;category_2\&quot;" name="\&quot;category\&quot;" size="0" lev="\&quot;2\&quot;" onchange="\&quot;getCategory(this);\&quot;">\n\t            <option value="\&quot;213\&quot;" t="\&quot;child\&quot;" title="\&quot;\u041c\u043e\u0431\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435" \u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\u044b\"="">\u041c\u043e\u0431\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\u044b&lt;\/option&gt;            </option><option value="\&quot;214\&quot;" t="\&quot;child\&quot;" title="\&quot;\u0410\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0443\u0430\u0440\u044b\&quot;">\u0410\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0443\u0430\u0440\u044b&lt;\/option&gt;></select></h5>'
```

How I can convert it in UTF 8?
PS: I try

```
 mb_convert_encoding($rezult, "UTF-8);
 iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $rezult);
```

But not rezult.

I have alredy found the solutoin:

```
function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
  return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}
echo stripslashes(
html_entity_decode(
     preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([\\da-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $rezult)
  )
);
```

Thank`s to all.

Comment: Remember to close the `"UTF-8"`

Answer (score -1):

```
$rezult = utf8_encode($rezult);
```